# SARGable way to find records near each other based on time window?

Tags: t-sql

We have events insert into a table - a start event and an end event.  Related events have the same internal_id number, and are inserted within a 90 second window.  We frequently do a self-join on the table:

```
create table mytable (id bigint identity, internal_id bigint, 
internal_date datetime, event_number int, field_a varchar(50))

select * from mytable a inner join mytable b on a.internal_id = b.internal_id
and a.event_number = 1 and b.event_number = 2
```

However, we can have millions of linked events each day. Our clustered key is the internal_date, so we can filter down to a partition level, but the performance can still be mediocre:

```
and a.internal_date >='20120807' and a.internal_date < '20120808'
and b.internal_date >='20120807' and b.internal_date < '20120808'
```

Is there a SARGable way to narrow it down further?
Adding this doesn't work - non-SARGable:

```
and a.internal_date <= b.internal_date +.001 --about 90 seconds
and a.internal_date > b.internal_date - .001 --make sure they're within the window
```

This isn't for a point query, so doing one-offs doesn't help - we're searching for thousands of records and need event details from the start event and the end event.

Thanks!

Comment: You might try [persisted and indexed computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to add +-90 seconds to internal_date.

Comment: That is dang clever and I hadn't thought of it.  It just seems odd that I can't get the optimizer to it SARGably.  That'll be my backup plan. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this index your query will be much cheaper:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_iid on mytable(event_number, internal_id)
INCLUDE (id, internal_date, field_a);
```

The index allows you to seek on `event_number` rather than doing a clustered index scan, as well as enables you to do a merge join on `internal_id` rather than a hash join. The uniqueness constraint makes merge join even cheaper by eliminating possibility of many-to-many join.

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/03/merge-join.aspx) for a more detailed explanation of merge join.

Comment: I'll look at this.  Offhand, though, the event_number isn't specific enough (1 or 2, in my example, so 50% selectivity).  I could (and I think _do_) have an index on `(internal_id, internal_date(-),  event_number)` that isn't being picked (and if I pick it, it's slower).

Comment: That's because bookmark look ups use random io instead of sequential io. So if you are going to retrieve 50% of the rows anyway, your best bet would be scanning over an index sequentially.